# Vim modifying a file if used with xxd

Tags: vim, mp3, raw-data, xxd

I'm trying to understand how ID3 tags work, so, after reading some documentation, I started to look at some mp3's raw data. Vim is usually my editor of choice, so, after some googling, I found out I could use xxd to see an hex representation of my files by invoking

```
:%!xxd
```

Everything worked fine, but when I put everything back in order with

```
:%!xxd -r
```

and quit, I found out that the file was modified; vlc could no longer play it, and diff told me the files differed. I thought I modified something by accident, but further experiments showed me that even opening the file and using xxd and then xxd -r changes somehow the file.

Why is that? How can I prevent it from happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: According to the example in [xxd manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd), to dump all edited bytes to another file (and avoid messing up original file), you need to specify file path in the vim command, e.g. `:%!xxd -r > /path/to/new/file`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously if you do not intend to change anything to a file you could quit `vim` using `:q!`.

As @RunHolt points out, `vim` and `xxd` can change a binary file. e.g. changing LF to CRLF or appending an LF character at the end of file.

You can prevent this by setting the `binary` option:

Either start `vim` as: `vim -b filename` or type `:set binary` before loading the file into the buffer.

Comment: By using the binary option everything worked fine. And yes, I know I could have used :q! to quit, but the main idea was to be able to modify the file via vim, so I had to find a way to save the file if necessary. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Odexios: You are welcome. I probably should not have mentioned the `:q!` command, but you never know, sometimes the most obvious things are the hardest to find.

Answer (score 2):

On windows binary files (not sure about other platforms), `:%!xxd` puts the end-of-file marker in the last two bytes (0x0d, 0x0a).  For some reason `%!xxd -r` doesn't remove them.

I often remove them manually (just delete both characters than run `%!xxd -r`)

Might be something that could be fixed directly with `xxd`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably did not load the file as a binary file with `vim -b`. I.e. the damage was already done.

`xxd` is a red herring here; `xxd` followed by `xxd -r` **is** transparent. It is intended for editing binary files. `xxd` does not add any bytes; it produces an accurate hexdump, which is accurately reversed by `xxd -r` (unless you corrupt it).

For viewing only, you could just run `xxd` from the shell:

```
$ xxd binaryfile | vim -     # just use vim as a reader
```

I've edited executables with `vim -b` and filtering through `xxd` and back through `xxd -r`. They ran fine.

Also, xxd is a Vim-specific program that comes with the Vim distribution. It might be useful to you to know `od`, e.g

```
od -tx1 file
```

Comment: Didn't know!  Also, you can `set bin` after the file has already been opened (before `xxd`).